# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 4C756E69

Tags: java, udp, objectinputstream

My apologies if this question has been asked numerous times but after hours of googling/experimentation I have not resolved my problem.

I'm trying to send an object (ServerPlayer) from my server over a UDP socket to my client and when the client receives the packet, I get an invalid stream header. I'm not sure what could be modifying the data to cause a corrupted/non-existent header.

Sender Thread:

```
//Thread loop
@Override
public void run()
{
    System.out.println("Thread " + threadCount + " running");
    //Test object transmission code.
    data = new byte[2048];
//  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  TRANSMISSION SETUP/OBJECT TRANSFER
    try 
    {
        //In case of delay
        socket.setSoTimeout(1000);

        //Object Transmission setup
        ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream);
        oo.writeObject(p);
        oo.close();

        //Transmit object
        data = bStream.toByteArray();
        packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, 4415);
        socket.send(packet);
//  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  GAME LOOP
        while(socket.getSoTimeout() > 0)
        {

        }
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  GET TO THE CHOPPA CODE BELOW
    } 
    catch (SocketException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Player " + username + " timed out");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Server: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Client/Receiver:

```
public MultiplayerGameStart() throws IOException
{
    address = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
    serverip = InetAddress.getByName(NetSettingsManager.ipAdd);

}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    //Packet byte array
    data = new byte[2048];
    try 
    {


        //Send connection REQ
        socket = new DatagramSocket(4415, address);
        data = PacketUtil.intTobyte(NetSettingsManager.NET_FUNCTION.REQ.getFunctionCode(), data.length);
        packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, serverip, serverport);
        socket.send(packet);

        //Wait for ACK
        packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        socket.receive(packet);

        //Converts ACK bytes to int to be read. If ACK code is correct, continue.
        if(PacketUtil.byteToint(packet.getData()) == NetSettingsManager.NET_FUNCTION.ACK.getFunctionCode())
        {
            //Returns username to be checked on playerlist.
            System.out.println("Logging into server..."); //DEBUG output
            data = NetSettingsManager.username.getBytes();
            packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, serverip, serverport);
            socket.send(packet);

            //Stub code below. Will receive player object generated by server.
            packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            socket.receive(packet);

            ObjectInputStream iStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength()));
            //iStream.reset();
            ServerPlayer messageClass = (ServerPlayer) iStream.readObject();
            iStream.close();

            space = new PlayState();
            space.addEntity(new ClientPlayer(received));



        }

    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Client: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Client: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ServerPlayer (Note, I have omitted my functions from this sample but I can provide them if needed).

```
public class ServerPlayer extends ServerEntity implements Serializable 
{
    int[] material = new int[4];
    Chunk pChunk;

public ServerPlayer(String username, float posX, float posY)
{
    super(username, posX, posY);
    //Material table.
    material[0] = 25;    //metal
    material[1] = 33;    //energy
    material[2] = 43;    //ion
    material[3] = 131;   //gas
}
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 4C756E69
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at client.multiplayer.MultiplayerGameStart.run(MultiplayerGameStart.java:80)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you for your time :).

**UPDATE**

So it turns out running my sender code in thread was causing problems. Now my packet outputs are

```
server:sent 243 bytes: -84,-19,0,5 | client: received 8 bytes -84, -19, 0, 5
```

but sadly I'm now getting

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at client.multiplayer.MultiplayerGameStart.run(MultiplayerGameStart.java:80)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

Comment: The loop on `getSoTimeout() > 0` is literally a waste of time. There's no point in testing that over and over again, unless you're changing it so as to break out of the loop, in which case you are misusing the facility.

Comment: The loop is left over code/experimentation from a few revisions back. I should probably delete it since it really isn't serving a purpose but at the time it was put to use.

Thank you for the response :)

Comment: The loop will never terminate, as the socket timeout has been set to 10000. Something seriously wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the calls to `reset()`. They don't add anything, and I believe that the server-side call to `bStream.reset();` is deleting the header written when you create the `ObjectOutputStream`.

Also, when you construct the `ByteArrayInputStream`, you should use the three-argument variant, passing `getOffset()` and `getLength()` from the datagram packet.

And in the future, when asking a question like this please post the actual stack trace from the exception, along with enough code to verify that the exception is happening where you think it is (in this case, the full receive method).

---

Edit: it appears that both client and server are sending and receiving to the same port (4415). Based on the additional debugging information you provided, I believe that the client is picking up the initial datagram that it tries to send to the server. Try using different ports for each (and use a constant such as `CLIENT_PORT` and `SERVER_PORT` to specify them).

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion/response but sadly it still throws the same error. I updated my post with your suggestions.

Comment: In that case, it's time for some debugging. First is to verify that what you're receiving is the same as what you're sending: print the first few bytes of `data` on both the server and client.

Comment: What Server sends: [B@39fae86
What Client receives: [B@68e26d2e

I believe the first two bytes are the header correct?
So something is operating upon the data before it enters the ObjectInputStream that causes it to throw that exception?

Comment: Print the actual bytes, not a `toString()`. On the server: `System.err.println("sent " + data.length + " bytes: " + data[0] + "," + data[1] + "," + data[2] + "," + data[3]);` On the client you'll need to do the same thing, but you'll need to take offset into account. *It's very important to print packet length on both sides*

Comment: Thank you very much for the continued replies. It helps immensely.

`Server: sent 250 bytes: -84,-19,0,5 | Client: Offset: 0 received 8 bytes: 76,117,110,105,116`

So it appears there is a good amount of data not being received.
Would it be wise to use a TCP socket to transfer these objects and then switch to a UDP socket for my game loop?

Comment: Actually, the data being received is completely different than the data being sent.